# Гиперссылка в ImageView

Tags: java

Не понимаю, как создать кликабельное изображение с гиперссылкой (знаю по части html, а что прописывать в java я не знаю).

Comment: речь про android или java fx?

Answer (score 4):

Допустим, у вас есть view:

```java
View imageView = findViewById(R.id.my_image_view);
```

На любую view можно навесить click listener следующим образом:

```java
imageView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
    // действие по клику
});
```

Чтобы открыть ссылку в браузере, нужно создать Intent и запустить его с помощью метода startActivity:

```java
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("https://example.com"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Соединяем все вместе:

```java
View imageView = findViewById(R.id.my_image_view);
imageView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("https://example.com"));
    startActivity(intent);
});
```